# how to format the datetime coming from database table in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still new to python ( am using version 3.x )

I have datas in my db table. one of the columns is date_created..when I query the data, and wrote the output in a json file the output is like this

```
'date_created': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 13, 7, 35, 0, 755315)
```

is there a way to format this field before writing to json file ?

like e.g

the field is `"date_created"` ...how should we format it in python 3 ? ...or or is there a way in flask ? (am actually using flask)

I want to see the output like this below

```
'date_created': '2020-04-13 07:35:00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_create.iso_format()`.

For UTC (this is the recommended way):

```
$ python -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat());'

2020-04-13T08:45:38.623199
```

Local time zone time stamp without timezone info (default behavior, not recomended)

```
$ python -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat());'

2020-04-13T14:12:34.181240
```

For timezone string:

```
$ python -c 'from datetime import datetime, timezone;print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat())'

2020-04-13T14:14:36.780896+05:30
```

Comment: none from your examples displayed what I solved myself..but I'll mark yours as the answers even if it's not. coz you gave tips that I might use someday..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using

```
date_create.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
```